# ¿Cómo realizo el siguiente arreglo?

Tags: c++

Ando un poco confundido al respecto no logro imprimir los datos.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
```

Esta es mi clase **Perro**

```
    class Perro
{
    private:
        string Nombre;
        string Raza;
        int i;
        int Edad;
        float peso;
        int NumeroVacunas;
        string Vacunas[];


    public:
        Perro(string Nombre = " ", string Raza = " ", string Vacunas="", int NumeroVacunas=0.0, int i=0.0, int Edad = 0, float peso = 0.0);

        void Leer(void);
        void Imprimir(void);

        ~Perro(void);
};
```

A continuación muestro las funciones:

Este es el constructor:

```
    Perro::Perro(string N, string R, string V, int NV, int i, int E, float p)
{
    Nombre = N;
    Raza = R;
    NumeroVacunas=NV;
    Edad = E;
    peso = p;
    i=i;
    Vacunas[NumeroVacunas]=V;
}
```

Con esta función asigno los respectivos valores creo que aquí es donde algo esta mal aunque si ejecuto el compilador si me deja asignarles valores:

```
void Perro::Leer(void)
{
    cout<<"\nIngrese el nombre del perro : ";
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin,Nombre);
    cout<<"Ingrese la Raza : ";
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin,Raza);
    cout<<"Ingrese la edad : ";
    cin>>Edad;
    cout<<"Ingrese el peso : ";
    cin>>peso;

    cout<<"\nIngrese el Numero de vacunas : ";
    cin>>NumeroVacunas;

    for(i=0 ; i<NumeroVacunas ; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Vacuna "<<i+1<<" : ";
        cin>>Vacunas[i];
    }
}
```

Con esta función los imprimo:

```
void Perro::Imprimir(void)
{
    cout<<"\nNombre : "<<Nombre;
    cout<<"\nRaza : "<<Raza;
    cout<<"\nEdad : "<<Edad<<" anios";
    cout<<"\nPeso : "<<peso<<" kg.";
    cout<<"\nVacunas : \n\n";

    for(i=0 ; i<NumeroVacunas ; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Vacuna "<<i+1<<" : "<<Vacunas[i]<<"\n";
    }

    cout<<"\n\n";
}

Perro::~Perro(void)
{
}
```

Este es el main y solo me deja leer la función leer pero no muestra los valores de los datos:

```
int main(void)
{

    Perro can;

    can.Leer();

    can.Imprimir();

    return 0;

}
```

Estoy intentado con apuntadores pero no sé si se pueda con cadenas de tipo **string**.

Espero que me puedan ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo raro es que hayas podido probar algo, pues tu código ni siquiera compila. Cuando defines una formación<sup>1</sup>, ésta debe tener tamaño:

```
class Perro
{
    private:
        string Nombre;
        string Raza;
        int NumeroVacunas;
        int i;
        int Edad;
        float peso;

        // ¿¡¿CUANTAS vacunas pretendes guardar aquí?!?
        string Vacunas[]; // <--- ¡ERROR!

    public:
        Perro(string Nombre = " ", string Raza = " ", string Vacunas="", int NumeroVacunas=0.0, int i=0.0, int Edad = 0, float peso = 0.0);

        void Leer(void);
        void Imprimir(void);

        ~Perro(void);
};
```

Sin tamaño, no puedes esperar guardar datos en posiciones de memoria que no existen:

```
Perro::Perro(string N, string R, string V, int NV, int i, int E, float p)
{
    Nombre = N;
    Raza = R;
    NumeroVacunas=NV;
    Edad = E;
    peso = p;
    i=i;
    // Si no se ni cuántas vacunas hay, ¿cómo voy a ir a la posición 'NumeroVacunas'?
    Vacunas[NumeroVacunas]=V; // <--- ¡ERROR!
}
```

Asigna un tamaño a la formación, y posiblemente se solucione:

```
string Vacunas[cantidad_de_vacunas_que_creas_conveniente];
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: ooooh vale,pero que tonto. Ya corrió mi programa. Muchas gracias.

Comment: **Si quisiera hacerlo con apuntadores,¿como seria la forma correcta de utilizarlo?**

*Por_Ejemplo*

`class Perro`
`{`
   ` private:`
        
       ` int i;`
       ` int NumeroVacunas;`
        `string *Vacunas;`


    `public:`
        `Perro( string *Vacunas=0, int NumeroVacunas=0.0, int i=0.0);`

        `void Leer(void);`
        `void Imprimir(void);`

        `~Perro(void);`
`};`

`Perro::Perro(string *V, int NV, int i)`
`{`
   ` NumeroVacunas=NV;`
    `i=i;`
    `Vacunas=new int[numeroVacunas];`
`}` 

**Para leer los datos inicialice el arreglo**

Comment: pero no me deja imprimirlos. @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: Si tienes una duda nueva, redacta una nueva pregunta.